# how to access a value in JsonArray with volley library

Tags: android, json, android-volley

My problem is that i can't find a way to access a value in a JSON object.

this is the format of my JSON:

```
 [
    {
        "title": "Foot - ANG - Eden Hazard (Chelsea) élu joueur de l'année de Premier League !",
        "link": "http://www.lequipe.fr/Football/Actualites/Eden-hazard-chelsea-elu-joueur-de-l-annee-de-premier-league/554292#xtor=RSS-1",
        "description": "Comme attendu, Eden Hazard a été élu ce dimanche joueur de l'année de... ",
        "pubDate": "Mon, 27 Apr 2015 00:20:00 +0200",
        "enclosure": {
            "@attributes": {
                "url": "http://medias.lequipe.fr/img-photo-jpg/football-chelsea-v-stoke-city-barclays-premier-league-stamford-bridge-4-4-15-eden-hazard-cel/1500000000558260/0:91,2048:1123-665-335-70/94bd6.jpg",
                "length": "50000",
                "type": "image/jpeg"
            }
        }
    }
```

and this is the code using Volley library. I can get the title but i can't get the url value under `attributes` object who is under `enclosure` object.

```
for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++)
                            try {

                                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                New aNew = new New();
                                aNew.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
                                // Genre is json array
                                JSONObject enclosureObj = obj.getJSONObject("enclosure");
                                JSONObject attributesObj = enclosureObj.getJSONObject("attributes");

                                aNew.setImageURL(obj.getString("url"));
                                newList.add(aNew);
                                //Log.e("items", "item added !");
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
```

the `EXCEPTION` is :

> 04-26 23:46:12.752 
>   11979-11979/customlistviewvolley.androidhive.info.customlistviewvolley
>   E/json Exception﹕ org.json.JSONException: No value for attributes

Comment: That Json is not valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i fix it.

```
JSONObject enclosureObj = obj.getJSONObject("enclosure");
JSONObject attributesObj = enclosureObj.getJSONObject("@attributes");
aNew.setImageURL(obj.getString("url"));
```

i forget the @ in `@attributes`